# List Picker Selection Change

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I have 2 list pickers which showing item name and batch number. Batch number depends on Item Name. So when selecting Item Name I want to bind Batch numbers to the second list picker.My code like this. I'm writen code for Item list picker `'SelectionChanged'` event. This is not working.

```cs
  private void lstItem_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (lstItem.SelectedIndex != 0)
        {
            int itemId = invoice.listItems[lstItem.SelectedIndex].ItemMasterID;
            getBatches = invoice.bindBatchesForItem(itemId);
            lstBatch.ItemsSource = getBatches;                
        }
    }
```

`bindBatchesForItem` will return the list of batch numbers for selected item.This method returning the batch properly. But  `'lstItem_SelectionChanged'` event calling twise automatically. First time executing properly and when second time executing attached error comming.[image: ERROR]

```cs
public ObservableCollection<BatchNumbers> bindBatchesForItem(int selectedItem)
    {
        listBatches.Clear();
        var batchList = from DailyItemStock DI in APPCommon.SFADB
                        where Convert.ToDateTime(DI.StockDate).Date == Convert.ToDateTime(APPCommon.TransactionDate).Date && DI.ItemMasterID == selectedItem
                        select new
                        {
                            DI.BatchNo
                        };

        listBatches.Add(new BatchNumbers() { BatchNo = "0" });
        foreach (var lists in batchList)
        {
            listBatches.Add(new BatchNumbers()
            {
                BatchNo = lists.BatchNo.ToString()                
            });
        }          
        batchList = null;
        return listBatches;
    }
```

[image: Screen]

Comment: Please elaborate what is not working? Also what `bindBatchesForItem()` method returns?

Comment: Ok, and what is not working specifically? Does `getBatches` get populated as expected?